# Hierarchy data binding to grid in a windows application

Tags: winforms, data-binding, devexpress

I have data setup like this..

Transaction
  -Name
  -ID
  -Amount
  -Tags <-- Array of Tags
    - Name

In a website, I could just loop through the tags and create spans of each tag with a link, I'm trying to figure out how to add this structure to a windows form application inside a XtraGrid (DevExpress)

Wanting it be like this..

    ID
       Name
         Amount
        Tags

   1
        MyTran
      13.02
             tag1 tag2  <-- each tag would be a linklabel with seperate event calls

I'm not sure how to accomplish this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [GridView.CustomDrawCell Event](http://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/DevExpressXtraGridViewsGridGridView_CustomDrawCelltopic) to format you display text, but you should not edit these tags using the gridview editors. you can change the display text of the cell (the [RowCellCustomDrawEventArgs.DisplayText](http://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/DevExpressXtraGridViewsBaseRowCellCustomDrawEventArgs_DisplayTexttopic) parameter.

```
private void advBandedGridView1_CustomDrawCell(object sender, RowCellCustomDrawEventArgs e) 
{
    //GridView currentView = sender as GridView;
    //if(e.RowHandle == currentView.FocusedRowHandle) return;
    if (e.Column.FieldName != "Tags") return;
    string[] arr = (string[])e.CellValue;
    string csv = String.join(',', arr);

    e.DisplayText = csv;
    // set e.Handles to true if you want custom drawing..
    e.Handled = true;
}
```

Check the custom drawing section links specified on *GridView.CustomDrawCell Event* documentation page.

> Another approach is that you store comma separated tags in you table
>   which you are binding with grid control. then you can edit those
>   without any problem. you have handle update, insert event with some
>   customizations and this will be much better than displaying custom
>   text.

Choose which approach suite you better. Hope this help.